# Remove particular word from filename

Tags: shell-script, find, rename

I have many files in a single folder like

```
compose_icon_200x200.png
mail_icon_200x200.png
attach_icon_200x200.png
delete_icon_200x200.png
```

I want to remove the _200x200 from all filenames.
I have tried

```
find . -name '*_200x200*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" echo $0' "{}" \;
```

But getting error like,

```
./mail_icon_200x200.png: ./mail_icon_200x200.png: Permission denied
```

Comment: That's a broken "recipe" that you found for renaming; was it from this site? We should correct it, if so.    Are there subdirectories with files, or are they all in the same folder?  Are you worried about collisions? (Files named "compose_icon.png" already)?

Comment: All files are in the same directory , there are no sub directories. There wouldn't be any collison since each file has unique name(sure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for f in *_200x200*; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f/_200x200/}"
done
```

or if you have the perl `rename` command:

```
rename 's/_200x200//' ./*_200x200*
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. But it would helpful if you explain the command. mv is for move. what does the other expressions do.

Comment: The rest is a for loop over files, and `${f/_200x200/}` is a regular expression subsitution.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(**/)(*)_200x200(*.png)' '$1$2$3'
```

(remove `-n` when happy).

Or for arbitrary dimensions:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)_<->x<->(*.png)' '$1$2$3'
```

(note that it removes only one occurrence of `_<width>x<height>` per filename).

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.png;
do
mv "$file" "`echo $file | sed 's/_200x200//'`"
done
```

Comment: That’s pretty much what the accepted answer does, only using `sed` instead of a parameter expansion...